# NTFS permissions issue: file cannot be read or modified in any way

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs

There are four of these files, in three directories. The files cannot be read, deleted, moved, or renamed. I have tried the Explorer permissions dialog, ICACLS, TAKEOWN, and SUBINACL -- all say permission denied. I am logged in as a member of Administrators. Running elevated does not help. Running as %COMPUTERNAME%\Administrator does not help.

The files are not open by any process, either local or remote.

Other files in these folders are perfectly readable, modifiable, deletable.

I even tried [running CMD.exe as LocalSystem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/11/27/271063.aspx) -- still couldn't access the files.

Since this is a live storage server, it will be some time before I can run a CHKDSK/F. Are there any other tools that might have luck with the files?

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Server is a domain member

Comment: Typically this is a sign of filesystem inconsistency. You're likely going to be stuck running `chkdsk`.  Are you picking up any NTFS errors in your System Event Log?

Comment: Nope.  (The comment I entered earlier, and deleted, saying that there were such errors, was about a different server.)

Comment: Do you get any type of message when trying to manipulate these files?

Comment: "Access is denied." when trying to `type`, `del`, `move` or `ren`. Similar messages from `ICACLS`, `TAKEOWN`, `SUBINACL`.

Comment: I worked around this for IIS purposes using (several) virtual directories... Will try `CHKDSK /F` on the weekend.

Comment: Why not run CHKDSK read-only to confirm or deny NTFS corruption?

Comment: The problem is moot now; that drive got destroyed in an unrelated disaster (stupid datacenter employee) and the data on that was it now lives on a new drive.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly a problem with the NTFS master file table.  Seen this very thing myself.  Reboot with CHKDSK flagged.

Comment: Well, instead of rebooting with chkdsk, I force-dismounted it (it was drive D, not C) and ran CHKDSK /F from user mode. It didn't help; after 45 minutes it still had not completed, and I had to abort because my time window was closing.